# What's the best SEO practice for http header content language on multilingual sites for audiences of the same region?

Tags: seo, http-headers, multilingual

Let's say for example I want to create a site for native speakers and a site where you will be redirected im your browser language is different from the native language.

For the default page I set the header for example to:
header('Content-language: fr');

But what would be better for the other page?

"es-fr" or just "es"? (for spanish speaking people in france in this example)

Answer (score 1):

If you have different version of Spanish pages for different regions, you can use "es-fr", else you can use as just "es". Example would be UK english and US english. We have different content, so we would setting the header accordingly, else we would just set it as "fr" for both Canada french and France french.

Answer (score 1):

I doubt you will find users set their browser settings beyond a language; if you specify "es-fr" and "fr" only, some Spanish-speaking folks (and search engines) may end up with French content.  I have my browser set to "en" primary and "es" and "it" as secondary, and I sometimes see ads served up to me in Spanish, and sometimes web pages served up in Spanish.